# Sort pandas multi-index by count?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have a dataframe, generated by a multi-index operation, that looks like this.

```
                      Col3
Col1        Col2
A              A1         N
B              B1         N
               B2         N
C              C1         N
               C2         N
               C3         N
```

I'm trying to sort this dataframe by the descending *count* of rows at level A, B, and C. In this case, level A has 1 row, B has 2 rows, and C has 3 rows...so the output would be

```
                      Col3
Col1        Col2
C              C1         N
               C2         N
               C3         N
B              B1         N
               B2         N
A              A1         N
```

I can think of doing this manually by actually counting the number of rows at each level and adding a column to the df to sort by, but is there a more elegant way? if so, is there a way to generalize to more levels?

Thank you!

EDIT: Code to generate original dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'z', 'x', 0.123], ['a','z', 'x', 0.234],
                ['a', 'z', 'y', 0.451], ['b', 'z', 'x', 0.453], ['b', 'z', 'x', 0.453], ['b', 'z', 'x', 0.453], ['b', 'z', 'x', 0.453]],
               columns=['first', 'second', 'value1', 'value2']
               ).set_index(['first', 'second'])
```

Running `df.ix[df.groupby(level=0).size().sort_values(ascending=False).index,:]` produces `TypeError: Expected tuple, got str`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you can do it by `groupby` on the first index level and sort the `size` and use this to reindex into your df:

```
In [25]:
df.ix[df.groupby(level=0).size().sort_values(ascending=False).index,:]

Out[25]:
          Col3
Col1 Col2     
C    C1      N
     C2      N
     C3      N
B    B1      N
     B2      N
A    A1      N
```

breaking the above down:

```
In [26]:
df.groupby(level=0).size()

Out[26]:
Col1
A    1
B    2
C    3
dtype: int64

In [27]:
df.groupby(level=0).size().sort_values(ascending=False)

Out[27]:
Col1
C    3
B    2
A    1
dtype: int64

In [28]:
df.groupby(level=0).size().sort_values(ascending=False).index

Out[28]:
Index(['C', 'B', 'A'], dtype='object', name='Col1')
```

**EDIT**

OK this was trickier than I expected but the following works:

```
In [76]:
i = df.index.get_level_values(0)
df.iloc[i.reindex(df.groupby(level=0).size().sort_values(ascending=False).index)[1]]

Out[76]:
             value1  value2
first second               
b     z           x   0.453
      z           x   0.453
      z           x   0.453
      z           x   0.453
a     z           x   0.123
      z           x   0.234
      z           y   0.451
```

So what this does is gets the first level index values and then `reindex`es them against the `groupby` result and uses the int index generated against the original df

Comment: When I run your suggested method, I get `TypeError: Expected tuple, got str`. The `df.groupby(level=0).size().sort_values(ascending=False).index` generates an Index object which has the correct values, but the actual indexing is failing. Any ideas?

Comment: What version pandas are you using? I'm running 0.18.0 and this works fine

Comment: I'm using pandas: 0.18.1.

Comment: can you post raw data and code that i can run to try and recreate the error thanks

Comment: Apologies....my original dataframe had more than one index column. Code to generate it is in the original question above.

Comment: this was a real pain to figure out and I think it really should've been easier

Comment: This works! Many thanks! I'm still coming to grips with pandas indexing....still a ways to go.